# Every line shows bold

Tags: font, iterm2, plugin-spf13

Somehow every line in my Vim is bold. I'm using Consolas, which has a Bold typeface. Also, after leaving Vim, terminal is shown in Regular. The screenshot shows a small document that should have both Regular and Bold. It only seems to change in color a bit.

[image]

I've had it working before, but even then, the difference between Regular and Bold was an absolute minimum. Using Vim with SPF13 and iTerm2.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally selected "Consolas bold" as the font for your terminal?

Comment: I’m wondering if this could be because of Vim’s theme. Some terminal emulators have a setting to draw brighter colors with bold.

Comment: It could be related to what `$TERM` is reporting as well. If it is set incorrectly then `t_Co` might be set to a low number. In my terminal if `t_Co` is 8 or less, than all text is bold.